# Usage of “à” in the sentence “Comme un enfant aux yeux de lumière”

Tags: prépositions, possessif

In the song *L'oiseau et l'enfant* by  Marie Myriam there is the line “*Comme un enfant aux yeux de lumière*”, which translate logically to “Like a child with light in the eyes”, but why is that so is not clear to me, due to the order of the words. “À” is used as preposition to indicate possession (like in the sentence *un ami à moi)*, but in the case “*Comme un enfant aux yeux de lumière*”, *enfant* comes before *yeux*, which suggest that the child belongs to the eyes, which makes little sense. So, what is the reason for this word ordering?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

La préposition *à* marque beaucoup d'autres choses que la possession.

> aux yeux de lumière

signifie

> *avec* des yeux (comme de la) lumière.

Bien sûr, on pourrait, en quelque sorte, dire que *aux* ici indique la possession puisque ça veut dire que l'enfant a (c'est à dire *possède*) des yeux de lumière. Mais quand on dit que *à* indique la possession on pense à  la construction suivante :

> le ballon à Paul

(construction d'ailleurs plutôt familière. C'est Paul (placé après *à*) qui possède la ballon.

Quand on dit:

> l'enfant aux yeux de lumière

on veut indiquer une spécificité de l'élément placé avant *à*, spécificité qui s'oppose implicitement à d'autres.

- Une voiture à pédales. (C'est donc pas une voiture à roulettes ou à essence)
- Une fille aux cheveux longs.( Elle n'a donc pas les cheveux courts ou le crane chauve)
- Un homme au regard pénétrant. (Il n'a donc pas le regard éteint)

---

*À* can indicate other things than possession although one could argue that in

> *un enfant aux yeux de lumière*

it could indicate possession since the eyes belong to the child.

When we say:

> *le ballon à Paul*

a colloquial construction to say that the ball belongs to Paul, *à* does indicate strict possession and the possessor comes after the preposition *à*.

Whereas when we say:

> *l'enfant aux yeux de lumière*

we indicate a certain quality or specificity of the person or object we are talking about. It is synonym of *avec* and the person or object that possesses that particular quality comes before the preposition *à*.

- *Une voiture à pédales.* (We mean a pedal car, as opposed to a toy wheel car)
- *Une fille aux cheveux longs*. (a long haired girl, as opposed to a short haired girl)
- *l'enfant aux yeux de lumière* (the child with light-like eyes.)

Answer (score 1):

one more time i found nothing to say but few things after reading the answer of "Laure"...

"à" in french comes from the latin "Ad" which is almost the "at"(@) of the modern english ,and can be used to express direction of action,location,time and sometimes possession...

> ça va nous pousser **à** faire telle ou telle chose

il s'agit de vers quelle direction va-t-on aller,agir...

> R.D.V **à** 17h:00

il est question de temps d'action

> une occasion **à** ne pas rater

on qualifie l'occasion de "à ne pas rater"

> il conduisait sur la route **à** 200km/h

il est question de manière ou de façon (comment conduisait-il ?)

> une démarche pas **à** pas

encore il est question de "comment" l'action se fait-elle(step by step/schritt fuer shritt)

> une machine **à** sous

les fameuses machines des casinos,quand à elles,elles n'ont pas de sous mais elles fonctionnent avec des sous !

-Dans

> comme un enfant aux yeux de lumière

"aux yeux de lumière" est un complément de nom ; ça complète le sens :
c'est comme si on avait un camera et qu'on va focaliser sur cet enfant pour le  distinguer de son environnement.c'est exactement comme dire

> l'enfant celui dont les yeux sont en lumière

Finally,it's worth mentionning that's about a song lyrics here and words order is important ..."lumiere" comes at the end of the sentence ,that's "à" pushed all the weight towards "lumiere" and why that choice of sentence construction.